# vmware is not able to ping windows laptop network

Tags: networking, vmware

I have windows 7 64 bit on lenovo laptop & on the same machine VMVare player 4.0.4 is installed.

A VM's first network card is NAT & second is host-only having fixed ip address.

I can ping VM's network from windows, but cannot ping windows from Vmware network.

The VM is Linux SUSE 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've had it occur to me. I simply disabled and re-enabled the ports in question :). that's the easy way to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Can other machines on your LAN ping the Windows machine in question? Try temporarily turning off the Windows firewall as a test. If that works then run this command to enable ICMP echo-requests:
 `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow`